# T-SQL LIKE using variable and index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-like

If [column1] is indexed, the next query may use index:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column1] LIKE 'starts%'
```

If I introduce a variable, the query below will never use index:

```
DECLARE @starts nvarchar(100)
SET @starts = 'starts%'
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column1] LIKE @starts
```

I want to implement StartsWith search based on user input and i'm not sure what way to choose:

1. escape user input properly for LIKE so optimizer will be able to pick a plan based on literal
2. use WITH(FORCESEEK)
3. use OPTION (RECOMPILE)

Comment: Another option is to look into fulltext search.

Comment: Why wouldn't your second query use an index?

Comment: i'm not planning to maintain full text search index for now

Comment: because of variable the second query compiles in some generalized way. I read that stuff somewhere on the internet

Comment: While focused more on parameterization than local variables, this dba post will probably be at least a bit useful: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33698/parameter-sniffing-vs-variables-vs-recompile-vs-optimize-for-unknown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another choice you didn't list. You can use the `OPTIMIZE FOR` option to force the query optimizer to make the correct assumption about the nature of the expected variable values. This seems to match your need very well.

```
DECLARE @starts nvarchar(100)
SET @starts = 'starts%'
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column1] LIKE @starts
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@starts = 'mnopq%'))
```

It's described in more detail in [this blog](http://sqlindia.com/option-optimize-for-parameter-sniffing-sql-server/). There is also the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714(SQL.100).aspx).

> Instructs the query optimizer to use a particular value for a local
>   variable when the query is compiled and optimized. The value is used
>   only during query optimization, and not during query execution.

Comment: i have to properly escape user input inside OPTIMIZE FOR statement anyway, right?

Comment: I have just tested this on AdventureWorks2008 and it doesn't work :( . [`QUERY`](http://tinypic.com/r/2nkl17d/8) and [`EXECUTION PLANS`](http://tinypic.com/r/4htpqb/8)

Comment: i tested and it works, however i don't see any advantage before the 1st choice

Comment: @svolkov - I don't understand your question about escaping user input. Can you include an example?

Comment: @M.Ali - sorry, I can't view your examples (social media block on my current network). I have used this feature before to get around parameter sniffing issues, and it does work.

Comment: @M.Ali - I looked at your images, and they show it does work. That's what you want to see - using the Var is able to use the index seek just like when you use a string literal. To see the alternative, use the Var in the LIKE, but without the OPTIMIZE FOR. Then the query plan will show a clustered index scan (i.e. a table scan), instead of the much better index seek.

Comment: @hatchet I'm building a query from code behind. It is executed as text. The main reason to introduce variables/parameters is to filter malicious user input. In your query I must provide both variable and literal based on unknown user input.

Comment: @svolkov - The literal is just there to direct the query optimizer. You would just come up with the literal once when you write your stored proc. It doesn't really matter what the literal is, except for where you place the '%' in it, which is the whole point. You could use the same literal 'mnopq%' that I used. Are you saying that the parameter coming in might be 'hello%' one time, and '%world' the next time? That was not how I read your question, since you say you're writing a "starts with".

Comment: @hatchet Thank you for the explanation. It's a smart trick you are offering

Comment: Sounded great but it does not work on our SQLServer 2019 neither.